# Is there another way to pass an object reference to an javascript anonymous function?

Tags: javascript

the html

```
<input type="text" value="teste" id="1" />
```

the javascript

```
function classe() {
    this.nome = "rodrigo";
    this.setup = function() {
        var ref = this;
        $("#1").keydown(function (event) {
            if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                $(this).attr("value", ref.nome);
            }
        })
    }
}

var obj = new classe();
obj.setup();
```

I was wondering if is possible to pass `this` into the nested function without having to save it to a local variable `ref` inside the parent function.

test code on: http://jsfiddle.net/7zorgou0/1/

Comment: What's wrong with the way you are doing it?

Comment: I think you want to put the `var ref = this` line above `this.setup = function`

Comment: nothing wrong. I want to understand if it is the only way!

Comment: There are undoubtedly other ways, but none as simple and (AFAIK) widely used as the method above. My only change, as noted, would be creating the local variable in the top level of your object scope. (Or of course use the `function(){}.bind(this)` method)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are more than one ways for this. You can instead create an immediately invoked function expression and pass `this` in there. But all of these methods are based around the same principle of closure.

Problem is, `this` variable is whatever the method is called upon. If you write obj.method(), then `obj` is the value of `this` for this execution.

Now, the inner method is declared as an event handler and not being called by you. It will be called by system when the event occurs. You can never be sure what object will be used for calling the method.

So if you want to reference outer `this` inside this handler, better save it as a local variable. The inner function will act as closure upon it and the variable will be accessible easily.

BTW, the IIFE variation which I wrote about above:

```
function classe() {
    this.nome = "rodrigo";
    this.setup = function() {
        (function(ref){
            $("#1").keydown(function (event) {
                if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                    $(this).attr("value", ref.nome);
                }
            })
        })(this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually [achieve that in ECMAScript 6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/arrow_functions#Lexical_this)!

```
class classe() {                           //Real class definition in JS!
    constructor(){
        this.nome = "rodrigo";
    }
    setup() {
        $("#1").keydown((event) => {
            if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                $(this).attr("value", ref.nome);
            }
        })
    }
}

var obj = new classe();
obj.setup();
```

The `this` won't change if the [`() => {}` syntax](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:arrow_function_syntax) is used.

Meanwhile in ES5 you can use [`.bind`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.5):

```
function classe() {
    this.nome = "rodrigo";
    this.setup = function() {
        var ref = this;
        $("#1").keydown(function (event) {
            if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                $(this).attr("value", ref.nome);
            }
        }.bind(this));
    };
}

var obj = new classe();
obj.setup();
```